# JSP JDBC SERVLET Showing classnotfound exception....Everything is correct

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

```
index.jsp

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>REGISTRATION</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="reg" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="user_name"><br>
EMAIL: <input type="text" name="user_email"><br>
PASSWORD: <input type="text" name="user_pass"><br>
<input type="submit"><br>
</form>
</body>
</html>



reg.java


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class reg
 */
@WebServlet("/reg")
public class reg extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String user_name = request.getParameter("user_name").toString();
        String user_email = request.getParameter("user_email").toString();
        String user_pass = request.getParameter("user_pass").toString();

            Connection con=null;
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.driver");
                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test","root","root123");
                Statement st=con.createStatement();
                int c=st.executeUpdate("insert into test values('"+user_name+"','"+user_email+"','"+user_pass+"')");
                if(c>0){
                    out.println("REGISTERD");
                }
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

Showing Exception 
Everything is in project ..Connector,database,table if user same code for simple java code it run but in servlet it show ClassNotFoundException
Help Me.
Thank You !

Following is exception

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.driver   at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
>     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)   at reg.doPost(reg.java:47)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: You need mysql connector. Download mysql jdbc driver .jar and add project library folder.

Answer (score 0):

If it works running from Eclipse, that means you have the MySql jdbc dirver jar in the classpath of your project, but it is not available to your web application.

The project class path (build path) is not the same as the class path of your web application when deployed. Not all jars being on your project class path get exported automatically.

Usually jars in the `WEB-INF/lib` will be available for the web application, but jars outside of that will not.

You should either place the MySql jdbc driver jar in `WEB-INF/lib`, or add it to the lib folder of your Servlet container (Tomcat in your case judging by the exception stack trace).